# Convert string Persian date to Gregorian DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, calendar

To convert a string Persian date to gregorian `DateTime`, 
I use date time picker and it sends me a string like `"۱۳۹۴/۰۲/۲۰"`

```
PersianCalendar p = new PersianCalendar();               
string[] d = start.Split('/');           
DateTime dt = new DateTime(int.Parse(d[0]), 
                           int.Parse(d[1]),
                           int.Parse(d[2]),
                           new HijriCalendar());
```

and my function that converts is

```
public static DateTime ToGregorianDate(this DateTime dt)
{
     PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
     return pc.ToDateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, 0, 0);    
}
```

It gives `DateTime` how can I send correct `DateTime` 
when it wants to convert shows this error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: `DateTime` constructor takes integer as a parameter and they are represented as [Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) in .NET Framework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two different problems:

- Arabic digits aren't supported by `DateTime` parsing
- `PersianCalendar` isn't part of any `CultureInfo`, so you can't use it directly while parsing the `string` to `DateTime` (and you can't set it to a preexisting `CultureInfo`).

Possible solution:

```
string date = "۱۳۹۴/۰۲/۲۰";
string date2 = Regex.Replace(date, "[۰-۹]", x => ((char)(x.Value[0] - '۰' + '0')).ToString());
```

Replace the digits from Arabic to decimal

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date2, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then parse the date ignoring the calendar

```
PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
DateTime dt2 = pc.ToDateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second, dt.Millisecond);
```

Then convert the date to the right calendar.

**This solution is broken because Persian Calendar months have a different number of days than Gregorian months**

Comment: you are parsing the Gregorian calendar of 1396, like medieval times... it will throw exception if days are not matched

Comment: @AlirezaJamali You are totally right.

Answer (score 6):

As I commented; [Eastern Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals) does not supported by `DateTime` parsing methods, it only accepts [Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals).

However, `char` type has a [`GetNumericValue` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k33ktz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which converts any numeric Unicode character to a `double`.

Let's use a combination of `char.GetNumericValue`, `string.Join` and `Int32.Parse` methods;

```
string d = "۱۳۹۴/۰۲/۲۰";
int year = Int32.Parse(string.Join("", 
    d.Split('/')[0].Select(c => char.GetNumericValue(c)))); // 1394
int month = Int32.Parse(string.Join("", 
    d.Split('/')[1].Select(c => char.GetNumericValue(c)))); // 2
int day = Int32.Parse(string.Join("", 
    d.Split('/')[2].Select(c => char.GetNumericValue(c)))); // 20
```

And then you can create a `DateTime` based on this values;

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

Then you can use;

```
PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
var dt1 = pc.ToDateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second, dt.Millisecond);
// {10.05.2015 00:00:00}
```

Comment: much like other answers, you are parsing the wrong year, 1394 in Gregorian calendar is different from Persian Calendar, with different days

Answer (score 3):

You have to convert Persian digits into `int` *manually, e.g.

```
    private static int ParsePersianNumber(String value) {
      int result = 0;

      // Persian digits are Unicode characters 0x06F0-0x06F9 
      foreach (var ch in value)
        result = result * 10 + ch - 0x06F0;

      return result;
    }

    ...

    String start = "۱۳۹۴/۰۲/۲۰";

    PersianCalendar p = new PersianCalendar();
    string[] d = start.Split('/');

    // int.Parse -> ParsePersianNumber
    // dt == 14 Mar 1974
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(
      ParsePersianNumber(d[0]), 
      ParsePersianNumber(d[1]), 
      ParsePersianNumber(d[2]), 
      new HijriCalendar());
```

Answer (score 2):

Map to Arabic numerals first:

```
var mapToArabic = 
  new Dictionary<char, char>{ 
    {'۰', '0'}, {'۱', '1'}, {'۲', '2'}, 
    {'۳', '3'}, {'۴', '4'}, {'۵', '5'}, 
    {'۶', '6'}, {'۷', '7'}, {'۸', '8'}, {'۹', '9'}};

var p = new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar(); 
var start = "۱۳۹۴/۰۲/۲۰";
string[] persian = start.Split('/');
```

The main change from your original code: Mapping from an array of Persian numbers (*year, month, date*), to an equivalent array containing the values in Arabic numerals:

```
var arabic = persian
                .Select(persianWord => 
                    new string(persianWord
                                .Select(persianChar => mapToArabic[persianChar])
                                .ToArray()))
                .ToList();
```

Now you can use that as you used the other one before:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(int.Parse(arabic[0]),
                           int.Parse(arabic[1]),
                           int.Parse(arabic[2]),
                           new System.Globalization.HijriCalendar());

var pc = new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar();
var result = pc.ToDateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, 
                            dt.Hour, dt.Minute, 0, 0);
```